# Truncate Widget Title

Tags: widgets, title

I'm using a function:

`function widget_new_title($title) {
    echo word_limiter($title,20);
}
add_filter('widget_title','widget_new_title');`

to limit the characters for widget title but my problem is that if I do this, the title is not wrapped in before_title and after_title as well as before_widget and after_widget.

Any help?

Thanks,
Cip

Answer (score 1):

don't use `echo` in filter functions - use `return`:

```
function widget_new_title($title) { 
return word_limiter($title,20); } 

add_filter('widget_title','widget_new_title');
```